# How to use the addTo method with String id and generator:'uuid' in Grails domain?

Tags: hibernate, grails

ENV:

```
Grails: 5.3.2
JDK: 11
```

I followed the official documentation at `https://docs.grails.org/5.3.2/ref/Domain%20Classes/addTo.html` to learn how to use addTo and encountered a problem:

Everything works fine when following the structure in the documentation. However, when I tried to declare the id of the domain as a **String type and specify its generation rule as 'uuid'**, things changed:

**Only** when the id of `Author` is changed to String and its generation rule is 'uuid', the addTo example code in the documentation can be executed correctly.

But once the id of `Book` is also changed to String and its generation rule is 'uuid', there is no data in the database after the code is executed."

Source code below:

```java
class Author {
    String id
    String name
    static hasMany = [fiction: Book, nonFiction: Book]
    static mapping = {
        id generator: 'uuid'
    }
}

class Book {
//    String id
    String title
    static belongsTo = [author: Author]
//    static mapping = {
//        id generator: 'uuid'
//    }
}
```

The `save()` function is called in the `Bootstrap.groovy`.

```java
class BootStrap {

    def init = { servletContext ->
        def fictBook = new Book(title: "IT")
        def nonFictBook = new Book(title: "On Writing: A Memoir of the Craft")
        def a = new Author (name: "Stephen King")
                .addToFiction (fictBook)
                .addToNonFiction (nonFictBook)
                .save()
    }
    def destroy = {
    }
}
```

Is there anyone who can give me a hand?

Comment: Try adding failOnError: true to the save call to see if that elicits some information.